# Logging in from iOS does not create a user in the MongoDB, does not call callback

Tags: ios, facebook, mongodb

I implemented Facebook login using the steps shown [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios), I am successfully redirected to Facebook where I can sign in and authorize my app.

The problem is that when I sign up using this method a a user is not created in the MongoDB, I have my website on my Facebook app set to `http://155.99.162.35:3000/auth/facebook/callback`

When I login through `localhost:3000/auth/facebook` the user is created successfully in the database.

Can anyone tell me how I can get the call back to be called when signing up through the iOS app.

Answer (score 0):

You should listen to the `FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate` protocol and make the call to your web server out of your app when logged in successfully.

To achieve this you should implement this delegate method, check whether the login was successful or not, and then sending a HTTP query to your server to create the user with the given information:

`- (void)
loginButton:    (FBSDKLoginButton *)loginButton
didCompleteWithResult:  (FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *)result
error:  (NSError *)error;`